# Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'OriginDestination' in type cast int flutter

Tags: android, ios, json, flutter, dart

I am trying to fetch data from a local json file in my assets. I received and decoded data and then tried to store it in a list for further use. But it give me the exception. I want the list to be of type `OriginDestination`, store it in database and then use it further. Can someone please tell me how can I parse data from json to OriginDestination.

Class OriginDestination -

```
OriginDestination cityDtoFromJson(String str) => OriginDestination.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String cityDtoToJson(OriginDestination data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
class OriginDestination extends HiveObject {

  @HiveField(0)
  City? origin;

  @HiveField(1)
  List<City>? destinations;

  OriginDestination({
    this.origin,
    this.destinations,
  });

  factory OriginDestination.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => OriginDestination(
    origin: City.fromJson(json["origin"]),
    destinations: List<City>.from(
        json["destinations"].map((x) => City.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "origin": origin,
    "destinations": destinations,
  };
```

Code where I am fetching data and want to use it (originDestinations is also a list of type OriginDestination) -

```
List<OriginDestination>? localOriginDestination = [];

  Future<void> readJson() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/files/node.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);
    localOriginDestination = await data["data"].cast<OriginDestination>();
    print(localOriginDestination);
    if(localOriginDestination!=null) {
      await _localStorageService.getBox().clear();
      await _localStorageService.getBox().addAll(localOriginDestination!.toList());
      originDestinations = _localStorageService.getOriginDestinations();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used Hive before but this line of code seems suspicious to me:

```dart
localOriginDestination = await data["data"].cast<OriginDestination>();
```

I think you want to do something along the lines of:

```dart
localOriginDestination = [
  for (final element in await data['data']) OriginDestination.fromJson(element),
];
```

But I can't be entirely certain without knowing what the value of `await data['data']` is.

---

Edit, adding some more information.

The `.cast` method on `List` is only meant to be used with a type that is a subtype of the original list type, like in this example:

```dart
void main() {
  List<num> nums = [1, 2, 3];
  List<int> ints = nums.cast<int>();
  ints.add(4);
  print(ints);
}
```

What you are doing is essentially the same thing as this.

```dart
void main() {
  List<Map<String, int>> items = [
    {'A': 1, 'B': 2},
    {'A': 3, 'B': 4},
  ];
  final result = items.cast<ABC>();
  print(result);
}

class ABC {
  int a;
  int b;
  ABC.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : a = json['A'],
        b = json['B'];
}
```

The problem here is that the `ABC` class is not a subtype of `Map<String, int>`. Classes are not maps in the dart programming language. You need to need to call the `.fromJson` constructor on each element of the `items` list in order to get a `List<ABC>`.

You can do it in a few different ways.

Using `map` method is one approach. (you need to be on dart 2.15+ for this exact syntax)

```dart
List<ABC> result = items.map(ABC.fromJson).toList();
```

Looping over items with a [collection for](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators) is another approach.

```dart
List<ABC> result = [for (final element in items) ABC.fromJson(element)];
```

Looping over items with a conventional for loop is yet another approach.

```dart
List<ABC> result = [];
for (final element in items) {
  result.add(ABC.fromJson(element));
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, you saved me. Can you please give me a link for documentation related to this?
I want to learn about this in detail.

Comment: I'm not certain what documentation you are looking for. You can't cast a json object to a dart class. The purpose of the `.fromJson` constructor is to convert json to your object.

Comment: I added some more information that will hopefully help with understanding.

Comment: Really appreciated bro. Thanks